# Python: saving a plot and not opening it in a GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to run a little program that should save my 3D scatterplot instead of opening it in a GUI. The problem is that it does both! This is the piece of code I'm talking about:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy import math
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')        
ax.scatter(xPosition, yPosition, zPosition, c = velocity, s = mass)
ax.set_xlim3d(-plotSize, plotSize)
ax.set_ylim3d(-plotSize, plotSize)
ax.set_zlim3d(-plotSize, plotSize)
pyplot.savefig('plot.png')
```

I would very much like to know how I can get a saved image of my plot without the plot being opened in a gui.

Comment: Try to add ``import matplotlib`` and ``matplotlib.use('Agg')`` at the beginning. It should enable the "headless" backend.

Comment: in my case, your script does not open the figure when run from an IDE (spe) on windows. to see the figure I need to especify `pyplot.show()`

Comment: Could it be because I'm working in Spyder?

Comment: I enabled the function in spyder that imports matplotlib, numpy and scipy automaticaly. Now everything is working just fine! Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: try adding `pyplot.ioff()` at the beggining of your code...

Comment: Can't you right-click and save the image? Unless you want to save the images directly without that manual process. It seems like you could though, as it is a .png file that is rendering.

Comment: I could do that but as I'm creating more than 4000 plots that doesn't look like à good option. Thans anyway.

Comment: I think if you change pyplot.savefig by fig.savefig it will work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pylab.ioff() as hilghlight by Saullo Castro, and each time you want to save a figure use pylab.savefig('file.png'). When you don't need the figure just do a pylab.close() to close the current figure (and free memory).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
pyplot.ioff()
fig = pyplot.figure()
# HERE your code to add things in the figure
pyplot.savefig('file.png')
pyplot.close()
```